# JavaScript; parsing an IF statement with OR clauses

Tags: javascript, short-circuiting

My question is quite simple, if I declare an IF statement with a series of OR clauses will JavaScript read all of the ORs or stop at the first one that is satisfied?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stops at the first one. It's called short-circuiting

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: Thanks davin. It's always easier when you know the correct term :)

Answer (score 1):

It should only process upto the first OR that returns true:

```
if (a || b || c) { 

}
```

If a is false, b is true and c is true, it will process upto b.

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo() {
    return true;
}

function bar() {
    alert("bar");
}

foo() || bar(); // true - no alert
bar() || foo(); // true - alert of "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first condition is satisfied, other conditions of `or` are not evaluated

Comment: The same with && in case of the first statement is false. (just adding some more info)